# Does AAA really provide Disney World discounts? Was I just ripped off?

Tags: travel, discount

Today I bought 2 day (august 20-21) "park hopper" for 3 adults from AAA .  So AAA charged me $821.

I'm looking at Disney's [website](https://disneyland.disney.go.com/tickets/)  and it looks like I might have got ripped off.  The same 2 day "park hopper" for 3 adults is $705.

That's just a regular price without any coupons and discounts.  Was I ripped off?

Comment: Are there any alternatives?

Comment: Tax? Did they actually promise you a discount, or was there some sort of add-on like souvenir or meal?

Comment: They told me I would get the best rates because disney is in some special relationship with AAA. and you have to be AAA client to get those rates.

Comment: Yes both numbers include tax

Comment: @Emily call them and ask for a price match? Lesson learned: don't just believe a sales pitch about "best price" or "special relationships". Compare prices on your own.

Comment: Are you quite sure the AAA deal doesn't come bundled with extra stuff?  AAA is a membership organization and in most states, a nonprofit.  They have no reason to fleece you.

Comment: Remember that prices at attractions like Disney may vary wildly based on time of year,  weather predictions, and anything else that might keep them from selling to capacity on that day... just as airline ticket prices are in a continual state of flux depending on similar factors. They may have adjusted price after you purchased. Or, if this includes hotel room, one pass may be at a more convenient hotel than another -- different amenities on site, different transportation to the park. You probably didn't get "ripped off", but you may or may not have gotten the best deal. Shop before committing

Answer (score 4):

AAA rarely provides discounts. They are kind of like a travel agent, and guess what? You can't get discounts from travel agents either. If AAA does have a discount, it will be on a very specific, simple ticket, not involving add-ons like park hopper.

Here is a guide to buying Disney tickets:

http://www.mousesavers.com/walt-disney-world-vacation-discounts-and-deals/walt-disney-world-ticket-discounts/#AAA

Answer (score 2):

I live in Minnesota.  I also heard about AAA discount Disney World tickets; so I called my local office to inquire.

Their prices were more expensive than just buying through Disney's site directly.  This was just for a basic, one park per day, three day ticket.

Go to mousesavers; then from there go to UndercoverTourist.

Comment: This duplicates the existing answer.